# Formatted print of linux kernel config

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, configuration, text-formatting

As the options **make menuconfig** and **make nconfig** allow a nice way to configure the kernel options, are there any way to get this hierachical structure for print it?

Something similar to the "tree" command ouput.

Comment: I haven't looked at it, but https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib may be a starting point, if you're interested. In particular: https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib/blob/master/examples/print_tree.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the replay of @jeff-schaller I did a contribution to the project Kconfiglib and now there is a new example script for this task. These are the steps to use it:

Inside the directory with the linux source, clone the repo:

```
root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# git clone git://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib.git
Cloning into 'Kconfiglib'...
remote: Counting objects: 3367, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Total 3367 (delta 64), reused 89 (delta 50), pack-reused 3259
Receiving objects: 100% (3367/3367), 1.25 MiB | 1.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2184/2184), done.
```

Patch the makefile:

```
root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# patch -p1 < Kconfiglib/makefile.patch
patching file scripts/kconfig/Makefile
```

Configure as needed, basically for get a .config file:

```
root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# make menuconfig
```

Run the script with the config file:

```
root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# make scriptconfig SCRIPT=Kconfiglib/examples/print_config_tree.py SCRIPT_ARG=.config

======== Linux/x86 4.9.65 Kernel Configuration ========

[*] 64-bit kernel (64BIT)
    General setup
        ()  Cross-compiler tool prefix (CROSS_COMPILE)
        [ ] Compile also drivers which will not load (COMPILE_TEST)
        ()  Local version - append to kernel release (LOCALVERSION)
        [ ] Automatically append version information to the version string (LOCALVERSION_AUTO)
        -*- Kernel compression mode
                --> Gzip (KERNEL_GZIP)
                    Bzip2 (KERNEL_BZIP2)
                    LZMA (KERNEL_LZMA)
...
```

But the nice thing is that it is possible to pass differente kernel configurations and match the changes easily:

```
root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# make scriptconfig SCRIPT=Kconfiglib/examples/print_config_tree.py SCRIPT_ARG=/tmp/config1 > config1-list.txt

root@23e196045c6f:/usr/src/linux-source-4.9# make scriptconfig SCRIPT=Kconfiglib/examples/print_config_tree.py SCRIPT_ARG=/tmp/config2 > config2-list.txt
```

And finally now with a diff tool:

[image: Kconfiglib with print_config_tree.py]